# How would I pass in various types of data via AJAX .post()?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to pass in mutliple data into AJAX .post(). This is what I've done so far:

```
$('form#tutorTableForm').live('submit', function()
{
    var cid = $('#courseSelect').val();
    var lid = $('#lessonSelect').val();
    var lessonCount = $('#lessonSelect option:selected').attr('id');
    $.post('', $(this).serialize(), function(response){
        alert(response);

    });
    return false;    
});
```

I want to also pass in cid and lid. How would I do that?

I'm using live instead of on because our app is using the old version.

Comment: ajax posts are covered all over the web in tutorials. also your question isn't very good.

Comment: You can post code in a code block (it'll even syntax highlight it!) - you don't need to use pastebin. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could create an object that contains all the data, like this:

```
var cid = $('#courseSelect').val();
var lid = $('#lessonSelect').val();
var lessonCount = $('#lessonSelect option:selected').attr('id');

var postdata = { 
          formdata: $(this).serialize(), 
          cid: cid, 
          lid: lid 
        };

$.post('', postdata, function(response){ alert(response); });
```

Answer (score 0):

place them inside the form as input hidden or whatever and the serialize should add them automatically. without seeing your html it's a bit difficult to see exactly what you need.